# In Ember.js templates, how does one print out model's property that will be use by HTML like the src for image or href for link

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Using:

- ember: v1.0.0-pre.4
- ember-data: revision 11
- handlebars: 1.0.rc2

So I have a template that I've hooked up to a controller that's receiving info from an REST API. In just print out text, this is fine but these handlebar expression...

```
<img src="{{ imageUrl }}"/>
```

...when inserted into the dom look like:

```
<img src="&lt;script id='metamorph-28-start' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;http://asdf.com/image.jpg&lt;script id='metamorph-28-end' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;">
```

I'm obviously very new to Ember.js and Handlebars.

I've tried doing searches for "rendering urls in ember templates" and "print out html in ember mustache templates." Ack, probably obvious but I'm missing it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

try this:

`<img {{bind-attr src="imageUrl"}} />`

but you can have more than just one attribute like:

`<img {{bind-attr src="imageUrl" alt="imageTitle"}}>`

here is the doc: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_bind-attr

also, can be useful in some cases where you don't need the variable to be bound, you could use:

`<img src="{{unbound imageUrl}}" />`

ref to the doc: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_unbound

but the first method is usually the best.

Comment: Honestly, it's embarassing how I could have missed bindAttr in the doc.

Answer (score 2):

Taking this a little bit further to get your feet even more wet, we can actually create a view that represents an image, and use that to add more functionality.

For instance, [in the following JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hXCRj/) I've set the view's `tagName` to `img` (where its default is a `div`), and then added an `attributeBindings` to bind attributes to the view. In our case we want to bind to the `src` attribute. All we then need to do is specify the `src` attribute as a property of the view, and give it a default value -- in this example, Google.

Therefore the view works as expected: we've displayed an image as part of a view.

However, taking it one step further, we can now easily change the image's `src` attribute by using the `.set()` method. On the magical `click` event, which is invoked when the user clicks on the view in the DOM (try it yourself by clicking on Google's logo in the JSFiddle!), the `src` attribute is changed from Google's logo to Yahoo's logo. Since we're observing the `src` attribute from `attributeBindings`, this is updated as soon as we call:

`this.set('src', 'http://l.yimg.com/dh/ap/default/120910/yahoo_logo_br.png');`

Full view code in case JSFiddle disappears:

```
App.ImageView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'img',
    attributeBindings: ['src'],
    src: 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png',
    click: function() {
        this.set('src', 'http://l.yimg.com/dh/ap/default/120910/yahoo_logo_br.png'); 
    }
});
```