# Insert an image with ember model

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an ember app where I'm pulling data via an api. The app code looks like this...

## index.html

```
<ul>
{{#each item in model}}
  <li>{{item.name}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

...and the api source data is json and looks like this...

```
{"shots":[{"id":1,"name":"joe1","avatar_url":"http://s3.amazonaws.com/daily_comedy_app/shots/avatars/000/000/001/original/1_985u645296.jpg?1392926501"},{"id":2,"name":"cgrim1","avatar_url":"http://s3.amazonaws.com/daily_comedy_app/shots/avatars/000/000/002/original/1_O7iwbEe.jpg?1392926554"},{"id":3,"name":"Mac","avatar_url":"http://s3.amazonaws.com/daily_comedy_app/shots/avatars/000/000/003/original/2014-03-06_12.48.16.jpg?1394146693"},{"id":4,"name":"wintas","avatar_url":"http://s3.amazonaws.com/daily_comedy_app/shots/avatars/000/000/004/original/1_O7iwbEe.jpg?1397231591"}]}
```

The code above in my index page loads fine, but I am not able to add the avatar_url. When I try...

```
<ul>
{{#each item in model}}
  <li>{{item.avatar_url}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

I get nothing....not even the path to the image.

I tried inserting an image tag like was suggested here...

[In Ember.js templates, how does one print out model's property that will be use by HTML like the src for image or href for link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590314/in-ember-js-templates-how-does-one-print-out-models-property-that-will-be-use)

...but I don't get anything on in the browser, and there are no errors in the console.

What am I missing?

## Update

//app.js

```
App.Shot = Ember.Model.extend({
  name: Ember.attr()
});

App.Shot.adapter = Ember.RESTAdapter.create();

App.Shot.url = "myapi.com/api/v1/shots?api_key=12d2d06fb2f6a786ac75b32625cf83a1";

App.Shot.collectionKey = "shots";
```

Comment: Can you post the model and controller code? Also, it's the name of the items shown?

Comment: Added model code above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your model definition is lacking the `avatar_url` attribute.

```
App.Shot = Ember.Model.extend({
  name: Ember.attr(),
  avatarUrl: Ember.attr()
});
```

Comment: Boom! You nailed it stravid...thanx!